# Unable to open Excel document after deleting Mac OSX Keychain

Tags: excel, macos, keychain

I deleted my Mac OSX (El Capitan) Keychain.  Everything except the certificates.  Now, when I go to open an Excel .xlsx doc Excel reports:

"Can't open This_File.xlsx.  This workbook is either deleted or not currently accessible."

I've verified that the file is present via Terminal.  If anyone can help figure out how to open this file I would certainly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since I deleted my keychain all of my Microsoft Office credentials that were tied to my work domain were also deleted, hence, I did not notice that I wasn't "signed in" to Excel (2016).  Once I signed in to Excel, which then redirected me to a domain authentication page, Excel still did not let me open my workbook from the "recent documents" GUI.  I had to open terminal and execute:

```
open /path/to/my/excel_workbook.xlsx
```

And then it opened.  I hope this might help someone else in the future.